# Ideal proof in a ring R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Problem Statement:

Let I be an ideal in a ring R. Prove that K is an ideal, where $ K $ = { $a\in R$ | $ (\forall r\in R)(ra\in I) $}

What exactly am I supposed to show here? I know I need to show that it's closed under subtraction and that it must absorb products from R for K to be an ideal.

For the last part ( absorption ) I'm assuming I'm supposed to show that if $ c \in R$ then $ cra \in I$ since I is an ideal in R and hence absorbs products, and thus is in K.

The set definition is throwing me off and I'm not even sure what the set K is supposed to be here.

Comment: I guess $K$ is the colon ideal $I \colon R$.which is equal to $I$.

Comment: I initially thought K was equal to I from the sets definition. But.. wouldn't that make this a bit of a redundant problem? Since if K = I it's already an ideal...? So, I was assuming that wasn't what the author meant.

Comment: In this case, the definition does look redundant, but the general colon ideal is defined as $I \colon J = \lbrace r \in R \mid r J \subset I \rbrace$ for ideals $I, J \subset R$.

Comment: The colon ideal $I:R$ is $I$ when $R$ has a $1$; otherwise the containment may be proper.

Comment: @fudges: Well I overlooked the possibility that $R$ is a rng, not a ring.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you have to show that the two defining properties for an ideal (subtraction and absorbtion) hold for $K$:

pick $a,b \in K$ and show that $a-b \in K$.

pick $a \in K$ and $s \in R$ and show that $sa \in K$.

To show this you will need to use the fact that $I$ is an ideal.

Notice that, when $R$ has a $1$, then $K = I$. Indeed, $I \subseteq K$ is clear by the absorbtion property of $I$. You get the other inclusion because the condition $ra \in I$ defining $K$ has to hold for $r=1$.